# How can I install Windows Server 2019 on a raspberry pi?

Tags: virtualbox, raspberry-pi, windows-server-2019

I want to install Windows Server 2019 on a raspberry pi, but raspberry imager doesn't let me for some reason. I think it's possible because if people can install windows 10 onto a raspberry pi. That means I can install Windows Server right? Or if I can't, can I install it into a VM that uses 100% of raspberry pi's power?

Comment: Make sure your Raspberry Pi supports 64-bit installations. My Pi is a 32-bit machine.

Comment: **You cannot** Windows Sever 2019 does not support ARM hardware.  What you want is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to install Windows Server 2019 on a raspberry pi, but raspberry imager doesn't let me for some reason.

It’s not being offered because Windows Server 2019 does not support ARM hardware.

> I think it's possible because if people can install windows 10 onto a raspberry pi.

Windows 10 on ARM and Windows 10 are two different products.

> if I can't, can I install it into a VM that uses 100% of raspberry pi's power?

You will be unable to run a 64-bit x86 operating system within a VM on your RPI.